# C# DatePicker Validating Date

Tags: c#, datepicker

DatePicker allows selecting a date.

UPDATE:
I would like to force DatePicker to allow only entry as dd/mm/yyyy.  So, if user tries to enter "December 21, 2015" it would not allow it.

I am in .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: `string[] f = { "dd/mm/year" };` <- `yyyy` instead of `year`. Anyway, `DateTime` has't any format you should think about it representation.

Comment: Dates have no format. It is how do you represent them on display that gives them a "format". If you get a date from the DateTimePicker do not try to "convert" it to some "format". Use it and when you need to display it use a format string (IE: _....ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");_)

Comment: @Steve I am not trying to represent them or convert to some other format.  All I want is DatePicker to allow entry only in dd/mm/yyyy format  and to make sure the date entered in in current year only.  Thank you

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks for catching that but changing to yyyy still does not resolve my issue.

Comment: You dont have an issue.  Setting the format of the DTP will just change how the user interacts with it.  You can restrict the range to this year by setting the Min and Max values.  Otherwise it will always return a valid date so there is no need to validate it.  Dates dont have formats, so there is no need to wrestle with that.

Comment: I update my question to clear missunderstanding.  Thansks

Comment: You are misunderstanding the fundamentals of `DateTime`.  A date is some long number internally. And when we output it in some format *that is a string*. The format tells what parts of the date to show and how - like months as text or months as numbers. Formatting a date never changes the date value. Two different formats of the same date are two strings, and they are different strings of the same date, but those strings are different.  DO NOT COMPARE OR VALIDATE DATES AS FORMATTED.

Comment: `How do I validate to make sure that the Date portion only matches format dd/mm/yyyy` You don't. It is "a null concept". `DateTimePicker` has properties for setting the format and it is what it is. you don't "validate what the format is.". You can enter the same date in any format, it is still the same date.

Comment: Your code is taking a DateTime object, making a string from it - in the format you define - and then parsing that string into a DateTime object. The net result is that the original time in the datetime was set to midnight - all zeros. Next, a DateTime object always is a date and a time. Your format may not show the time, but it is there. Parsing `12/17/2015` to a datetime defaults the time to midnight - all zeros.  When comparing dates the entire datetime value is always used. Also, `StartDate.Date` is the date time with the time set to midnight.

Answer (score 1):

To catch cases where the text typed into the DatePicker is not a valid date format you should handle the [`DateValidationError` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.datevalidationerror(v=vs.110).aspx).  You'll get passed a `System.FormatException` if the format isn't acceptable.

To limit the drop-down Calendar to the current year you can set the [`DisplayDateStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DisplayDateEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend(v=vs.110).aspx) properties - but that doesn't stop you typing other dates in the text box.

```
MyDatePicker.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
MyDatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
```

To limit the DatePicker to the current year set the [`BlackoutDates` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates(v=vs.110).aspx) to exclude all dates other than the current year.  For example:

```
// Exclude all dates before the start of this year
MyDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(
   new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31)));
// Exclude all dates after the end of this year
MyDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(
   new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 1, 1), DateTime.MaxValue));
```

A validly formatted date that falls into one of the blackout date ranges will cause an ArgumentOutOfRangeException to be passed to the DateValidationError event handler

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Comment: I am using DatePicker and I can not set anything you specified

Answer (score 0):

Try this to validate the date range starting from today to 30 more days.

```
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Today;

this.DateTimePicker.MinDate = new System.DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day);

this.DateTimePicker.MaxDate = today.AddDays(30);
```